# I want to express 2 kinds of balance in one sentence, How?

Tags: phrase-request

I want to express something like this:

> we should pay same attention to certain teams and normal staff; and we should provide food to certain teams and normal staff.

Actually I think it's not just simple "same", so I'm thinking about using "keep ...in balance", or "balance ..." (or any other including "balance") to combine above in one sentence.

Comment: what about "equal"?

Comment: How about *as well as*?

Comment: Also, *same to ..., as ...* - with *and* you're comparing both to some abstract third thing; with *as* you compare one to the other.

Comment: What do you mean by "certain teams" -- not all teams, only some teams?

Answer (score 1):

Why does it have to be a single sentence? Why not:

> We should pay equal attention to certain teams and normal staff. We should also provide them with food.

Notice the "equal" instead of "same" -- if you prefer "same" in your example it would be "the same."

If for some reason a single sentence is important, then Mamta's suggestion is a good one, but I'd still streamline it:

> We should pay equal attention to certain teams and normal staff, as well as provide them with food.